# Django SMTP and secure password authentication

Tags: python, django, smtp, ntlm

I have an SMTP server that requires secure password authentication (e.g. Outlook requires to check SPA). Is there a way to deal with it with Django SMTPConnection?
Or maybe ideas about any python solution to deal SPA?

Honestly, I couldn't find enough about SPA, to understand what is it exactly:

- en.wikipedia:Secure_Password_Authentication
- http://www.kuro5hin.org/?op=displaystory;sid=2002/4/28/1436/66154

Comment: According to Wikipedia SPA "is a proprietary Microsoft protocol used to authenticate Microsoft email clients with an electronic mail server". It isn't very well know, since almost everybody uses SSL authentication (which obviously is supported in Django).

Comment: Unfortunately, i have to deal with SPA on SMTP server, and no chance to have TSL. So I need any suggestions about python+SPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [python-ntlm project](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm) is a working implementation of NTLM authentication for urllib2. There is a patch floating around in the tracker that allows [integration with smtplib](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/issues/detail?id=14).

I would install python-ntlm, then fork smtplib inside your Django project (making sure it gets imported through smtplib) and then patch either smtplib (to always use ntlm authentication) or django (to use python-ntlm).

This will get the work done.

Comment: Finaly this solution was applyed. The main problem in the beginig was misunderstanding that SPA equals NTLM for my purposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After googling for it I found the same question asked on Google Groups:
http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/fc7f77e2f796e6a4/90ae093cbb2863b8?pli=1

> SPA is a proprietary MS protocol for
>   which there is no documentation.  I
>   don't think you will find a non MS
>   implementation of SPA.